# How do you make specific collisions in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

So I have created a "game" where you are automatically running across platforms and you can jump and land on the top of them.
 I want to set it where if you collide with the the left and right side of the platform a death function executes. 
How can I implement a collision mechanic to achieve this?[What I want the collision to be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOFKz.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is covered in the Unity tutorials. Basically you add colliders to those walls (with specific tags) and then check in your code if you have collided with one of those "death walls".

Answer (score 8):

One approach to this issue is to examine the [Collision Normal](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint-normal.html).  This is a vector that describes the direction along which the other object is pushing back.

[image]

Here is a minimal example of the concept.  You will likely want to tune the condition to suit your needs (at the moment a corner collision may be erratic where `x ≈ y`).

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    Vector3 collisionNormal = collision.contacts[0].normal;
    if (Mathf.Abs(collisionNormal.x) > Mathf.Abs(collisionNormal.y)) {
        //horizontal collision
    }
}
```